# Sinon not mocking method

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, sinon

I want inject into constructor database client, but when I run tests, mocha throw exception, that  method whitch is called is not a function.

```
 export class CustomService {
    constructor(database: any) { 
       database.init().then((res)=>{}));
    }
} 


describe('CRUD service', ()=>{
    it('when i decide save item', ()=>{
        let db =   sinon.mock(new DatabaseService);     

        let instance = new CustomService(db);
        db.expects('init').once();
        db.verify();
    });
});
```

In console:

> TypeError: database.init is not a function

What is wrong?

Comment: it might not be the answer but Round bracket is missing at `new DatabaseService`

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass the *return value* of `sinon.mock` to the code you are testing but instead pass *the original object* you passed to `sinon.mock`. The return value of `sinon.mock` is only for setting assertions and checking them. You also need to set the order of the statements in your tests so that the expectations are set *before* the code that must satisfy them is run. Something like this:

```
describe('CRUD service', ()=>{
    it('when i decide save item', ()=>{
        const db = new DatabaseService();
        let mock =   sinon.mock(db);     

        mock.expects('init').once();
        let instance = new CustomService(db);
        mock.verify();
    });
});
```